# Why is the following function holomorphic: $f_n(s)=\int _{[n\rightarrow n+1]}z^{-s}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

Note: $Re(s)>0$. Also $z^{-s}=e^{-s* Ln(z) }$

I know that $\int _{[n\rightarrow n+1]}z^{-s}dz$ =  $\int_{n}^{n+1}t^{-s}dt$ but that does not help.

Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: Hint: thanks to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem your statement reduces to proving that $\oint \int_{[n,n+1]}z^{-s}dzds=0$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I considered that but does that mean we have to invoke Fubini's at one point?

Comment: That or another theorem to exchange integrals

Comment: But we have to show that f is continuous as well right?

Comment: That is not hard to do, since $e^{-s\ln(z)}$ is a continuous function of $s,z$ and the domain of integration is bounded

Comment: Just to clarify, when you use fubini's you use the fact that $e^{-s*ln(z)}$ is holomorphic in s therefore the inner integral becomes 0 right?